# How to change the alsa specific device audio volume using shell?

Tags: linux, bash, fedora

How to tell use `hw:1,0` not `hw:0,0` when I am changing the alsa using my shell script?

e.g:

```
amixer sset Capture 10%+ unmute

$ amixer -D AK5370 sset Capture 10%+ unmute
ALSA lib control.c:882:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL AK5370
amixer: Mixer attach AK5370 error: No such file or directory

$ amixer -D 1 sset Capture 10%+ unmute
ALSA lib control.c:882:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL 1
amixer: Mixer attach 1 error: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No really, how come you got that specific a command, know about alsa device naming and are inable to type `man amixer` and find that `-D` does that?